# Is it possible to replace Cloud SQL proxy with Istio proxy?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, istio, cloud-sql-proxy

Currently I am using Cloud proxy to connect to a Postgres Cloud SQL database as a sidecar. When using Istio, however it introduces its own sidecar, which lead to the result that there are two proxies in the pod. So I thougth, can the encrypted connection not also established using Istio?

Basically, [it is possible to connect to an external IP using Istio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094753/istio-connect-to-an-external-ip).

[It should also be possible to configure a DestinationRule which configures TLS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343583/how-can-i-use-custom-client-certificate-for-external-service-with-istio)

[And it also be possible to create Client certificates for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ssl-instance#client-certs).

EDIT: might be the same problem: [NGINX TLS termination for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542830/nginx-tls-termination-for-postgresql)

So I ended up with something like

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-db
spec:
  hosts:
    - external-db
  ports:
    - number: 5432
      name: postgres
      protocol: TLS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: STATIC
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: external-db
spec:
  host: external-db
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: MUTUAL
      clientCertificate: /etc/certs/client-cert.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/client-key.pem
      caCertificates: /etc/certs/server-ca.pem

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-db
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-db
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.171.48.3
    ports:
      - port: 5432
```

and in the pod with

```
sidecar.istio.io/userVolumeMount: '[{"name":"cert", "mountPath":"/etc/certs", "readonly":true}]'
sidecar.istio.io/userVolume: '[{"name":"cert", "secret":{"secretName":"cert"}}]'
```

**However, the server rejects the connection. So the question is, can this setup possibly work? And does it even make any sense?**

Comment: Hi @user140547 this seems to be a very specific configuration issue, as everything in theory, should work. For this reason, I would recommend you to reach out to [Google's Support](https://cloud.google.com/support), so they can investigate deeper what might be affecting your instance.

Comment: @gso_gabriel in the meantime, I found this post: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/204720ce-a817-0ab3-3c51-5c950960b95c%40proxel.se
So maybe it is not possible to simply proxy this without taking in account the application-level protocol, although that is about replication.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Postgres uses application-level protocol negotation, so Istio/Envoy cannot be used in that case:

https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/10942
https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/9577#issuecomment-606943362

Comment: Did you find any solution? I really prefer having nginx take care of the SSL business. So that I don't have to fiddle with server specific SSL config. Also, if I have to rotate the certs those servers need not be restarted. I don't know why Postgresql does not allow this usage pattern.

Comment: @Dojo unfortunately I didnt. actually for GCP and Cloud SQL there is a Cloud SQL Proxy, which handles key management and rotation, so for me the issue was not that urgent. It would just be nice if I didn't need two sidecar proxies.